# Calling sock.recv() after sock.sendall() in Python

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, socketserver

I provided a WORKING client and server file.
The client sends a picture to the server.
When you comment out:

```
data = sock.recv(1024)
print("received: ",str(data,"UTF-8"))
```

the picture will not be uploaded to the server anymore...
(After receiving the upload message from the server I would like to upload another picture in the future.)

So why is calling sock.recv() after sock.sendall() messing up the communication ? ( and how should I solve it )

Client.py :

```
import socket
PICLOC = "/home/wr/Documents/Data/cola_big_1.jpg"
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9995

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:

   # Connect to server and send data
   sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

   # Send a command to the server
   command = "pictureRequest"
   data = sock.send(bytes(command, "utf-8"))

   pictures = []
   pictures.append(PICLOC)

   data = sock.recv(1024)
   print("received : ",data.decode())

   for picture in pictures:
       # sending a picture to the server
       f = open(picture,'rb').read()
       numBytes = len(f)
       x = str(numBytes)
       print("numBytesToSend: ",x)
       data = sock.sendall(f)
       '''
       data = sock.recv(1024)
       print("received: ",str(data,"UTF-8"))
       '''
finally:
   sock.close()
```

Server.py

```
import socketserver

HOST = "localhost"
PORT =  9995

TARGETPICLOC = "/home/wr/Documents/Data/Received/cola_big_1.jpg"

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):


  def findProduct(self):
    """
        Method called to find the product
    """

    # Receiving command from the client
    msg = "ok to send" 
    data = self.request.sendall(bytes(msg,"utf-8"))
    print("send msg")

    # TODO 6 pictures in array !
    # Sending a picture from client to server  
    pictures = []
    pictures.append(TARGETPICLOC)


    for picture in pictures:
        total_data=[]

        # open the target picture-file 
        newFile = open(picture,'wb')

        data = self.request.recv(1024)
        newFile.write(data)
        total_data.append(data)
        while len(data)>0 :
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            newFile.write(data)
            total_data.append(data)

        data = b''.join(total_data)
        print("#bytes : ",len(data))
        newFile.close()

        msg = "picture uploaded"
        data = self.request.sendall(bytes(msg,"utf-8"))
        print("msg send ")


  def handle(self):

    # Receiving command from the client
    data = self.request.recv(1024)
    command = str(data,"utf-8")
    print("command: ",command)

    if command=="pictureRequest" :
        self.findProduct()

    print("Request ended !!")



if __name__ == "__main__":
   HOST, PORT = HOST,PORT
   server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
   server.serve_forever()
```

Thank you for looking at this problem

Answer (score 2):

> So why is calling sock.recv() after sock.sendall() messing up the
>   communication ?

That's simply because the client by this `sock.recv()` call waits for data from the server (you intend to receive the `picture uploaded` message from the server), but the server is stuck in the loop

```
        while len(data)>0 :
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
```

since `recv()` still waits for data from the client and blocks. If the `sock.recv()` call is omitted, the client gets to `sock.close()`; only thereafter `self.request.recv(1024)` returns zero length data, so that the server can sense the end of the transmission and escape the `while` loop.

> ( and how should I solve it )

You could send the number of bytes to send (`x = str(numBytes)`) to the server prior to sending the picture, so that the server then could loop while the length of `total_data` is less than this number.